How to calculate the average number of examined hash values before the first collision?
I am trying to calculate the average number of examined hash values before the first collision occurs. I need to calculate the empirical average and the theoretical average.
Here is the function definitions:
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from sympy import sieve
import random
import math
import binascii
class HashFunctionTaskC:
    
    upper_bound = 1
    
    def __init__(self, upper_bound):
        self.upper_bound = upper_bound
    
    def get_hash_value(self, message = None):
        if(None==message):
            sys.exit("No message is given!")
            
        # Padding empty string
        if(len(message) == 0):
            message = "0"
        
        hash_value = ord(message[0])
    
        # The hash value is generated by taking the product (modulo 365) of the ordinal numbers of characters at the positions indexed by prime numbers
        for i in sieve.primerange(len(message)):
            hash_value = (ord(message[i-1])*hash_value)%self.upper_bound
    
        return hash_value


# Implement the birthday attack for a hash function
def birthday_attack(message_space, hash_function):
    
    has_collision = False
    tried_hash_values = set()
    collision_pair_1 = -1
    collision_pair_2 = -1
    
    random_index_samples = random.sample(range(len(message_space)), len(message_space)); # Random sampling without replacement
    
    for i in range(len(message_space)):   
        hash_value_1 = hash_function.get_hash_value(message_space[random_index_samples[0]])
        tried_hash_values.add(hash_value_1)
        for j in range(1, len(random_index_samples)):
            hash_value_2 = hash_function.get_hash_value(message_space[random_index_samples[j]])
            if hash_value_1 == hash_value_2:
                has_collision = True
                collision_pair_1 = random_index_samples[0]
                collision_pair_2 = random_index_samples[j]
                break
            else:
                tried_hash_values.add(hash_value_2)
                    
        if has_collision:
            break
        random_index_samples = random.sample(random_index_samples[1:], len(random_index_samples[1:]))
    
    if has_collision:
        return len(tried_hash_values), collision_pair_1, collision_pair_2
    else:
        print("No collision is found!")
        return -1, -1, -1    

I currently have the below code which runs a birthday_attack function 1000 times:
num_examined_b4_col = 0
i = 1
while i <=1000:
    count, cp1, cp2 = birthday_attack(message_list, HashFunctionTaskC(upper_bound=365))
    num_examined_b4_col+= count
    i+=1
num_examined_b4_col = num_examined_b4_col/1000
print("the average number of examined hash values before the first collisionis:",num_examined_b4_col)

The above code spits out a number around 32 which I believe be the empirical average.
My issue is calculating and comparing the theoretical average to the empirical average. I presume that the empirical and theoretical average should be similar especially given that I have used the law of large numbers to reliably calculate the empirical average.
All my attempts of calculating the theoretical average have resulted in averages far below the expected value of around 32: I calculated the theoretical average to be 19.1 using the square root of 365 (which is the total amount of possible hash combinations for the given algorithm).
I'm not entirely sure where I am wrong here. Am I calculating the empirical average or the theoretical average incorrectly? Or perhaps there is an issue with how the hashing algorithm has been built and it has a lower entropy than expected?

You need to supply the missing code for birthday_attack, HashFunctionTaskC, the generation of message_list, and anything else needed to reproduce your results.
